# How do I create a computed field?

Tags: webforms

I'm creating a Webform in Drupal 8. On the form, I have two number fields; when a user populates them with values, a third field will display the value of the two field multiplied together.

How can I create that computed field?

P.S. If the user changes the values in either the fields, I need the value in the computed field to update on the fly.

Comment: check this module
https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field
And See this After install the computed filed https://www.urbaninsight.com/2012/07/30/working-drupal-computed-field-module

Comment: Also this module which can do both addition and multiplication of other fields on a form: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_calculation_components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a recipe for [How to implement client-side calculations](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-implement-client-side-calculations).